# How do I disable “Flat Rate” radio button and remain with other shipping method in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have two shipping methods and i want to disable default flat rate shipping method. I have tried this way which posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47718180/hide-shipping-methods-for-specific-shipping-class-in-woocommerce) but its not working

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_method_based_on_shipping_class', 10, 2 );
function hide_shipping_method_based_on_shipping_class( $rates, $package )
{
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // HERE define your shipping class to find
    $class = 92;

    // HERE define the shipping method to hide
    $method_key_id = 'flat_rate:7';

    // Checking in cart items
    foreach( $package['contents'] as $item ){
        // If we find the shipping class
        if( $item['data']->get_shipping_class_id() == $class ){
            unset($rates[$method_key_id]); // Remove the targeted method
            break; // Stop the loop
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the values of these below variables of your code-

```
// HERE define your shipping class to find
$class = 92;

// HERE define the shipping method to hide
$method_key_id = 'flat_rate:7';
```

Though the author of [source answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47732732) clarified how to get these above things in the answer, here I'm putting these again.

**Finding the shipping class ID.**

1) In the database under `wp_terms` table:

Search for a term name or a term slug and you will get the term ID (the shipping class ID).

2) On Woocommerce shipping settings editing a "Flat rate", with your browser html inspector tool, inspect a shipping Class rate field like:

[image]

In the imput name attribute you have `woocommerce_flat_rate_class_cost_64`. So 64 is the ID for the shipping class.

---

**Get the shipping method rate ID:**

> To get the related **shipping methods rate IDs**, something like **`flat_rate:12`**, inspect with your browser code inspector each related radio button attribute **`name`** like:
>
> [image]